# onclick on image from .setAttribute('onclick', 'imgClick(this)') how to get index of image

Tags: javascript, html

From the code, it will display many image, but how to get index value from image that i click, because i need to now what image index that i have click.

```
for(var i = 0; i<keys.length;i++){
var images=packageuid[k].imageUrl;
buildImages(images);

function  buildImages(images){
var last=document.createElement("img");
last.src=images;
last.setAttribute('onclick', 'imgClick(this)')
display.appendChild(last);

function imgClick(img) {
//
```

Answer (score 1):

Attach the listener properly with Javascript instead, and use `let i` instead of `var i` for block scope, and the listener's closure can close over the `i` for that iteration:

```
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  const imageUrl = packageuid[k].imageUrl;
  buildImage(imageUrl);

  function buildImage(imageUrl) {
    const imageElement = document.createElement("img");
    imageElement.src = imageUrl;
    imageElement.addEventListener('click', () => imgClick(imageElement, i));
    display.appendChild(imageElement);
```

Then the second argument passed to `imgClick` will be the index:

```
function imgClick(imageElement, index) {
```

Comment: all picture capture same index. when click

Comment: Did you make sure to use `let i` rather than `var i`, as the answer says?

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer to indicate that the issue is resolved :)